# Memory churn when using WebSocket fallback (HTTP streaming using XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, websocket, xmlhttprequest, http-streaming, forever-frame

In a WebSocket fallback using HTTP streaming I can see that `XmlHttpRequest#responseText` is invoked each time the `readystate` changes (and is >= 3).

The WHATWG living standard says that [the text response is](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#text-response)

> ...the result of running `decode` on received bytes using fallback encoding charset.

I think this means that a new string with a size corresponding to the result of encoding into UTF-16 *all* data received since the HTTP streaming request was made is created each time the `readystate` changes in this way.

I have observed periodic (i.e. for the periods where the HTTP streaming response buffer is larger - it is reset periodically) large amounts of memory churn in the JavaScript heap when using this technique with around five messages inbound to the client per second and think it is linked to the above approach.

Does this sound a reasonable analysis?

Has anyone found any techniques to reduce the impact on the memory subsystem of this HTTP streaming technique (eg. shortening the life of each HTTP streaming connection)?

Comment: Your analysis is correct. For which browsers do you still need fallback?

Comment: IE11, Firefox 40+ and Chrome 40+ unfortunately due to current backend infrastructure not supporting WebSockets. Do you have experience in this area?

Comment: I help maintain both standards (XMLHttpRequest and WebSocket), but I don't think I can offer much practical advice here. Sorry.